# Jenkins Always Complains Missing File

Tags: jenkins

New to Jenkins.
My pipeline is very elementary:

```
def COLOR_MAP = ['SUCCESS': 'good', 'FAILURE': 'danger', 'UNSTABLE': 'warning', 'ABORTED': '#D3D3D3']
def AUTHOR= ''
def SLACK_CHANNEL = '#build'

def repoName
def appConfigName='config.txt'
def envFileName='.configrc'
def envFileNameTest='.configrc.testing'
def artifactName='mysoft' 
 
def attachmentPayload = """[{
    "text": "hahaha",
    "thumb_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/b1/d4/5db1d41e3cc0c6eae7e1910a7939bfa4.jpg",
    "color": "danger"}]"""
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile { 
            filename "Dockerfile.build" 
            label 'docker-cli'               
            args "${env.dockerInDocker}" 
            additionalBuildArgs '-t mysoft-ci' 
            reuseNode true          
        }
    } 
    options {
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()   
        timestamps()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Loading Environment Configuration') {
            steps {
                sh 'rm -rf temp && mkdir temp'                
                dir('temp') {
                    checkout changelog: false, poll: false, 
                    scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], 
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                    extensions: [], 
                    submoduleCfg: [], 
                    userRemoteConfigs: [
                        [
                            credentialsId: 'gitCredentials', 
                            url: "https://<my-git-repo>/configuration.git"
                        ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
                sh "cp -r temp/$artifactName/Pre-prod/${appConfigName} ../${envFileName}"
                sh "rm -r temp"             
                
            }
        }

         

        stage('Sanity Test') {          
            steps {
                script {
                    dir(path: '/app/src') {
                        try {
                            sh 'python -m pytest --junitxml=reports/result.xml'
                        }
                        catch (exc) {
                            echo 'Something failed, I should sound the klaxons!'
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
       
        stage('Sonar') {
            environment {
                SONAR_API_TOKEN = credentials('SonarToken')
            }
            steps {
                 script {
                    def scannerHome = tool 'SonarScanner';
                    withSonarQubeEnv('sonar.mycompany.io') {
                        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
                    }
                    timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
                        waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: false
                    }
                }
            }             
        }
      
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                sh 'touch reports/*.xml'
                junit 'reports/*.xml'
            }           
            slackSend channel: SLACK_CHANNEL,
                 color: COLOR_MAP[currentBuild.currentResult],
                 message: """
                 The pipeline ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} completed with ${currentBuild.currentResult},  after ${currentBuild.durationString}. ${currentBuild.absoluteUrl}. Committer $AUTHOR """
        }
        success {
          echo 'This will run only if successful'
        }
        fixed {
            slackSend channel: SLACK_CHANNEL,
                  color: COLOR_MAP[currentBuild.currentResult],
                  message: "Great, $AUTHOR has fixed the build."
        }
        regression {
            slackSend channel: SLACK_CHANNEL,
                  color: COLOR_MAP[currentBuild.currentResult],
                  message: "Ahaha $AUTHOR has broken the build.",
                  attachments: attachmentPayload
        }       
    }
}
```

But Jenkins always says:

```
Error when executing always post condition:

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: dockerNode, node, dockerNode

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:266)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:263)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor703.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)

    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)

    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)

    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)

    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:93)
```

I don't see any error during the preparation stage of the docker. Anyway the Docker.build follows:

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.10-nodejs16-slim

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin" 
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.3.0
ENV POETRY_HOME=/usr/local/bin/poetry
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/root/.cache


RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc make build-essential git sudo && \
    apt-get install  -y --no-install-recommends coinor-cbc  openjdk-17-jre-headless ca-certificates-java && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install  --no-cache-dir poetry
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app 
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \    
    poetry install && \
    rm -rf ~${POETRY_CACHE_DIR}/pypoetry/{cache,artifacts} && \
    pip cache purge && \     
    poetry shell 
    
RUN groupadd docker && \
    usermod -aG docker node 

# Timezone: very important!
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime && echo "Europe/Rome" > /etc/timezone
WORKDIR /app/src
```

Comment: The error is because of the `sh` and `juint` executions in the post build section.
These steps require a `node` context to run on and should be executed as part of the pipeline stages and not in the post section. If you do want to run them in the post section wrap them with the relevant `node` context.